# Do pressure levels correspond to elevation?

Tags: weatherdata, climate-data

I am trying to download climate projection data and am only interested in the surface temperature, radiation, etc.

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/projections-cmip6?tab=overview

The vertical coverage is Single levels or pressure levels (1 - 1000 hPa). Which one represents values at the surface, say between 1-20 meters above the ground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the near surface features explicitly (click "Single levels" radio button). Then select each variable that has "near surface" or "surface," in the name or is intuitively a surface property (such as sea level pressure).

For your own edification, pressure levels decrease with height. The 1000 hPa level corresponds with the ocean surface. This would be fine, but things like mountains, [where the pressure can be significantly smaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest#Meteorology), obscure the field.